# How to get culture-specific Full Name using CultureInfo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cultureinfo

I am trying to find to evaluate name in format specific for user culture.

```
Full Name= First Name + Last Name
```

Is there any method to so this in CultureInfo class and all it properties?
Where can I find such format string for each culture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CultureInfo will not do this for you.  What you are most likely looking for is a culture sensitive name dictionary/library.  They tend to be rather pricey.